# Having problems with Webview from another activity Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, android-studio

I have a project called `PubliComidas`, In my project there are 3 activities. The first is `SplashScreen`, Second is my `MainActivity`, third is a `WebView` which is loaded on button click in `MainActivity`,  Problems is that the webview is not working as I expected.

When I run my app and click on the button, it shows: `Web page not avalaible net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`, However it's so curious because I tried to test the same code in another project apart, P.D,  it was tested in only 1 blank activity when you start for the first time a new project, same steps and it works perfect but not in this app so is it a problem with this activity? or the webview cannot be shown with a lot of activities, my first and Second activity work fine but the third not, my idea is to display google. My goal is to display twitter feeds but first if it doesn't work with google even it won't work with twitter. Some help is highly and strongly appreciated, thank you!!

here is my code

**Twitter.java**

```
package com.example.json.publicomidas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class Twitter extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.co.cr");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

            mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MyWebViewClient.java**

```
package com.example.json.publicomidas;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("www.google.co.cr")){
            return false;

        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;


    }


}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.json.publicomidas" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.json.publicomidas.Twitter"
            android:label="@string/twitter" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.json.publicomidas.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.json.publicomidas.Splash_Screen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_twitter.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images"
    tools:context="com.example.json.publicomidas.Twitter">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The permission declaration should be outside of the application tag. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.json.publicomidas" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.json.publicomidas.Twitter"
            android:label="@string/twitter" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.json.publicomidas.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.json.publicomidas.Splash_Screen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```